# Dial call using C#.net by AT Commands

Tags: c#, at-command

I want to make a c# program that connects to my mobile phone by usb cable to make just a call. I found how to connect by SerialPort and how to make call by AT Commands, but when I run my program and click to make the call, nothing happens. This is my code, please Help me:

```
SerialPort SP = new SerialPort("COM3");
SP.BaudRate = 9600;
SP.Parity = Parity.None;
SP.DataBits = 8;
SP.StopBits = StopBits.One;
SP.RtsEnable = true;
SP.DtrEnable = true;
SP.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
SP.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
SP.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
SP.Open();
SP.Write("ATDT 0999182542"+ Environment.NewLine);

SP.Close();
```

Comment: No space in that string; see whats going on http://www.serialmon.com/

Comment: @hazoomo how can i get mobile phone sim modem in system com port. By simply connecting USB cable, it doesn't show any com port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all to see if your modem is connected, send an `AT` command to the port. If you get a `OK` as response, then it means your modem is connected.

To make a call the syntax is:

`ATDYourphnumber;`  //Donot forget the **";"**

Example: `ATD9012345645;`

So you should write to the port the same way.

Syntax:

`SP.WriteLine("ATD"+phonenumber+";");`

You can use *WriteLine* since that serves the `\r\n` too.

**Update:** How to see the response from modem:

After *SP.Open( )* ;

```
string cmd = "AT";
SP.WriteLine(cmd + "\r");
SP.Write(cmd + "\r");
Thread.Sleep(500);
string ss= SP.ReadExisting();
if(ss.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))
  {
   MessageBox.Show("Modem is connected");
  }
```

Comment: I suggest your remove `SP.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;`
`SP.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;`. There aren't needed in your case.

Comment: plz i dont know how to return ok

Comment: oh my god.... anything you send to the modem you will see it in the res
ex: SP.WriteLine("James"); // res is James
    SP.WriteLine("AT") ;  // res is AT
please what the problem ....:(

Comment: Yes `res` will hold everything present on the port. So when you execute the above code if the modem responded with `OK` then `res` will contain OK and you can understand that modem is connected, else it isn't connected to that port.

Comment: Note that it may happen that your modem may take more than 200 micro sec time to respond. So try with larger time values if you doubt the code isn't working.

Comment: Im sorry I have missed the carriage returns in the previous code and probably that was the issue. Try the modified code above.

Comment: Cdeez i discovered my problem is the same in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834784/com-port-driver
but no one solution it
i am very sure .....

Answer (score 2):

@Cdeez Your answer is the best! it works just fine XD I tried but my mistake was not including the "\r" which works as pressing "enter", and you need to press enter for the command to take action. By the way here is my method for calling, and thanks @Cdeez once again !:

```
private void Call() {
        SerialPort celu = new SerialPort();
        celu.PortName = "COM13"; // You have check what port your phone is using here, and replace it
        celu.Open();
        string cmd = "ATD";  // Here you put your AT command
        string phoneNumber = "784261259"; // Here you put the phone number, for me it worked just with the phone number, not adding any other area code or something like that
        celu.WriteLine(cmd + phoneNumber + ";\r");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string ss = celu.ReadExisting();
        if (ss.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Modem is connected \r Calling : " + phoneNumber);
        }
        celu.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I want to play a message when user attend call may you help me, please

Comment: @UmairRasheed sorry I cannot help you, I lost this project on an old computer, and don't have it in a repo, so it is hard to remember what I did there. Please share your solution if you found it!

Answer (score 0):

What about COM port logging tools. Do you use it? Did your commands send to COM port?

As far as I know dial command is ATD[Number]; so try to rewrite your code as follows:

```
    SP.Write("ATD0999182542;"+ Environment.NewLine);
```

Try to use this library:
[GSM Communication Library](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm)

Comment: No nothing happen i think the problem in Serial port how to know if my mobile connected ???please

Comment: Do you use any com port monitor?